# How to derive $\frac{dE}{dt}=-\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism

I see this formula in a lecture note:

$$\frac{dE}{dt}=-\frac{\partial L}{\partial t},$$ where $E$ is the energy and $L$ is the Lagrangian.

How do I derive this formula?

I know how to derive $\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}$, how do I get from this equation to the above equation?

Comment: Hint: How do you define the energy $E$?

Answer (score 1):

By the chain rule. $$\frac{dH}{dt}-\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}=\sum_i \left( \frac{\partial H}{\partial q_i}\dot{q}_i+\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i}\dot{p}_i\right).$$The right-hand side vanishes by Hamilton's equations, so$$\frac{dE}{dt}=\frac{dH}{dt}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}$$(where the leftmost equation assumes we define "energy" as the Hamiltonian).